# Declaring a different compile path for CoffeeScript

Tags: scala, coffeescript, sbt, scalatra

I have a Scalatra app that compiles CoffeeScript, using https://github.com/softprops/coffeescripted-sbt, to a default location, `target/scala-2.9.1/resource_managed/main/js`. I want to put the generated javascripts somewhere available to me publicly, in a folder called `src/main/webapp/coffee`, but the example given defaults to `/target/...'

```
resourceManaged in (Compile, CoffeeKeys.coffee)) <<= (crossTarget in Compile)(_ / "your_preference" / "js")
```

My build.sbt:

```
seq(coffeeSettings: _*)

// doesn't work
//(resourceManaged in (Compile, CoffeeKeys.coffee)) <<= ("src" / "main" / "webapp" / "coffee")
```

How would I reference the path I want the compiled assets to go into inside `build.sbt` correctly, if it's `src/main/webapp/coffeee`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to your build.sbt:

```
//compiles your CoffeeScript files to resource_managed/main/webapp/js/
(resourceManaged in (Compile, CoffeeKeys.coffee)) <<= (resourceManaged in Compile)(_ / "webapp" / "js")

//makes ALL files in resource_managed/main/webapp as static file available
com.github.siasia.PluginKeys.webappResources in Compile <+= (resourceManaged in Compile)(_ / "webapp" )
```

src/main/coffee/example.coffee will be available at `http://localhost:8080/js/example.js`

Comment: This doesn't work.

<script src="resource_managed/main/webapp/file.js"></script>

Requesting "GET /resource_managed/main/webapp/file.js" on servlet "" but only have:
GET /

Comment: Sorry, changed the directory structures, but it still didn't find the reference. <script src="js/anotherdirectory/example.js"></script> returns the same error above.

Comment: maybe you need the absolute path (path starts with slash /) 
<script src="/js/anotherdirectory/example.js"></script>. Is your coffee file in src/main/coffee/anotherdirectory/example.coffee?

Comment: Schleichardt: Thanks for the help. We're trying out your GIST and still getting the "directory not found" error. It's a blank proj. I put it here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2070388/hackapp.zip

Do you see something we are doing wrong?

Comment: Actually, this worked... we had some other junk in the project. Great answer.