# From Play! to Scalatra, templating headaches, directory structures

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework, underscore.js, scalatra

I'm trying to convert a Play! 2.0 [application](https://github.com/franklovecchio/playback) into a Scalatra [application](https://github.com/franklovecchio/scalatraback). I've had some success, but there are 3 issues remaining, 1 of which has its own [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595453/declaring-a-different-compile-path-for-coffeescript).

1) I understand that `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views` and `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/layouts` contain the layouts in a standard directory structure. I was not able to get this to work in a different heirarchy, though, e.g. if I have **2 servlets** and wanted different views for them:

```
- WEB-INF
 - servlet1
   - views
   - layouts
 - servlet2
   - views
   - layouts
```

In the example I provided, I can't adequately reference anything not directly under `WEB-INF/views` or `WEB-INF/layouts`. Presumably, it's because I'm not declaring something in `web.xml` correctly?

```
// works
get("/") {
  contentType = "text/html"
  templateEngine.layout("/WEB-INF/views/app.jade")
}

// no worky
get("/") {
  contentType = "text/html"
  templateEngine.layout("/WEB-INF/servlet1/views/app.jade") // where servlet1/layouts/default.jade exists
}
```

2) What's up with templating? For this conversion to work, I need to be able to use Underscore templates in conjunction with whatever is available to me from Scalatra (Jade, Mustache, etc). I chose Jade because all the default examples use it.

I'm really running into two sub-issues here.

1) I can't seem to use Underscore templates with Jade, even though I have included the javascripts in [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528885/using-jade-templates-in-backbone-js). Maybe this works, maybe it doesn't. This is probably because....

2) My `include` statements look like tags instead of actually including the partial, so it's really hard to test the first sub-issue.

```
<!-- / Nav -->
<include>nav</include>
<!-- / Action1 -->
<include>action1</include>
<include>action2</include>
<!-- / Wireframe -->
<div id="default-region">
  <script id="template-layout" type="text/template">
    <div id="region-nav"></div>
    <div id="region-content"></div>
  </script>
</div>
<!-- / CSS and JavaScripts relative to Backbone app -->
<include>assets</include>
```

What the equivalent `app.jade` file looks like:

```
// Nav
include nav

// Action1
include action1
include action2

// Wireframe
div#default-region
  script#template-layout(type="text/template")
    div#region-nav
    div#region-content

// CSS and JavaScripts relative to Backbone app
include assets
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Side comment: You can get rid of the `div`s in your Jade file. They are default. Is easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can structure your views differently or you have to provide a different filesystem configuration for your views.  You can configure that by [overriding getRenderContext](https://github.com/scalatra/oauth2-server/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalatra/oauth2/OAuth2ServerBaseApp.scala#L158-L175).

You don't need to call templateEngine.layout, but instead use our helper methods.
For jade with a layout that becomes `jade("my_view", "layout" -> "/WEB-INF/layouts/authenticated.jade")`

As for including those tags, etc. perhaps you mean [this](https://github.com/scalatra/oauth2-server/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/angular.jade)?

Comment: I'd rather keep it all here, just in case someone else needs the info! When I call jade("my_view", layout = "..."), "layout" throws an error. It looks like it's expecting a Map[String, Any], so I'm a bit confused, now.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake in the code sample. I've edited it.  there's also an example of this in the docs: http://scalatra.org/guides/views.html#layouts